# dateRestrict in google custom search using Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-custom-search

I've been trying to use the google custom search.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

my_api_key = "MASKXXX"
my_cse_id = "MASKXXXX"

date = "2016-01-01:2016-01-02"

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, dateRestrict=date, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']

results = google_search('crude oil site:www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/', my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=5)
for result in results:
    # pprint.pprint(result)
    print result['title']
    print result['snippet']
```

The above code works, but I want the results to return the articles for a particular date. I am trying to use the option dateRestrict, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried various formats but none seems to work. What could be the problem? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing, and dateRestrict didn't seem to work. The pages that were not in the date range also appeared.
The workaround I found is to use the sort feature. The query will look something like this:

(q='search_term' , cx='search_engine_id', sort = 'date:r:yyyymmdd:yyyymmdd')

The sort feature allows us to sort and filter the date of the results to the time range specified.